# Oracle SQL: After insert number of rows are different from SQL Window than Command Window

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

First of all, I inserted 2 million rows into the table, like this:

```
SQL> execute sp_inserts_2_million_rows();
```

And then, when I count the number of rows in the SQL Window as follows:

```
select count(*) from my_schema.my_table t;
```

it returns:

```
    COUNT(*)
1   13302072
```

But if I do it in the command windows like this:

```
Connected to Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 
Connected as XXX@YYY

SQL> select count(*) from my_schema.my_table;
```

It results in:

```
  COUNT(*)
----------
  15519084
```

What is going on? How can I synchronize both results?

Comment: check if there are any other process running in parallel or check if there are any statements without DCL inside the function you are running to load data. The count shouldn't differ with the tool.

Comment: 13302072 != 2M.  Confused.  Did you do a commit?

Comment: I did commit like this: SQL> COMMIT WORK; Commit complete, and 15519084 - 13302072 ~= 2M

Comment: "SQL Window" and "Command Window" sound like you are using PL/SQL Developer. If so, maybe you have it set to open different windows in separate sessions. However, you have tagged Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, it is necessary to add the line:

```
COMMIT WORK;
```

Inside the stored procedure.

Comment: No, it does not have to be done inside the procedure.  But it _does_ have to be done in the same _session_ in which the DML was executed.